# Error when trying to save indexPath to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsindexpath

I am trying to save the indexPath for UICollectionView, but I get the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My code is:
Save index path:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:indexPath forKey:@"CollectionIndex"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Load indexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *storedIndexPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CollectionIndex"];
```

I have commented out code to find out which code that makes the error, and it is the code I am using to save the indexPath that creates the SIGABRT error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the documentation of `NSUserDefaults > setObjectForKey`:

> > "The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects. See “What is a Property List?” in Property List Programming Guide."

To save an indexPath in the UserDefaults, you would have to make another representation, e.g. as a dictionary:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@{@"row": @(indexPath.row),
                                                   @"section": @(indexPath.section)}
                                          forKey:@"CollectionIndex"];
```

Comment: Oh, I see.. @jaydee3 do you know about an other way to save and load the indexPath?

Comment: Complementing the answer of @jaydee3 , you can not save objects created by oneself. Even if you try to save them into array or dictionary.

Comment: Going need to wrap the row and section in an NSNumber to put them in an NSDictionary.