# NSUserDefaults does not save indexPath for Selected Cells

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, cells

I am aware that I can't save an indexPath in NSUserDefaults. I want to save the cells that the user selects so when the user opens the view controller AGAIN -- the selected Cells in Collection view are DISPLAYED. However, the code below doesn't save the selected cells. The first block of code is suppose to save the selected cells (but doesn't) and the second block of code says this code will never be executed (stated below).

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@{@"row": @(indexPath.row),
                                                       @"section": @(indexPath.section)}
                                              forKey:@"CollectionIndex"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSIndexPath *storedIndexPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CollectionIndex"];

    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:storedIndexPath];

    myCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    myCell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 6; 

    return myCell;

}
```

My collection view
CODE WILL NEVER EXECUTE

```
if (collectionView ==self.septView) {
    // Call identifier
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6;

    // cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


    // Color
    self.septView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Label
    self.titles = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, cell.bounds.size.width, 40)];
    self.titles.tag = 0;
    self.titles.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.titles.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.titles.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:15];
    self.titles.text = [self.sept objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.titles];



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to save indexPath to NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509911/error-when-trying-to-save-indexpath-to-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: I used that code, but it never worked. Updated my question though. The NSIndexPath I created and implemented does not work. Which the question you posted doesn't cover. I think I wrote a wrong line of code under `CellForItemAtIndexPath` @the4kman

Answer (score 0):

You can get your index path in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this:

```
    NSDictionary *storedIndexDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CollectionIndex"];
    NSInteger row = [[storedIndexDictionary objectForKey:@"row"] integerValue];
    NSInteger section = [[storedIndexDictionary objectForKey:@"section"] integerValue];

    NSIndexPath *storedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```